# How to deploy parent project packaging war in maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Could anybody suggest me an solution with the following exception. I am going to create a multi-module project.

Parent project name is `projectW` and child project names are `projectA`, `projectD` and `projectUtil`.

I need to have war file of `projectW` which should contain `projectA`, `projectD` and `projectUtil`.  jar file.

But maven must pom for packaging in parent project. How can I create a project like this?

Comment: `projectW` can not be the parent Project, because a parent Project is packaging type `pom`. All Projects shoulb be child Projects of a parent Project `projectP` and `ProjectW` should be have the other Projects as dependencies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a parent pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>example</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>example</name>

  <modules>
    <module>projectW</module>
    <module>projectA</module>
    <module>projectD</module>
    <module>projectUtil</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

Then projectW pom looks something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>projectW</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>projectW</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>projectD</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.example</groupId>
      <artifactId>projectUtil</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Then your projectA, projectD and projectUtil will looks something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

When you build the parent, the war you want will be projectW/target/projectW-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war