# Building Maven Projects, Independent of IDE (esp. ecplise)

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, intellij-idea, gradle

I inherited a .Net/Java Project combo, in which there are different "modules" some modules are dependent on others, some are independent. It is not a true multi module project (No aggregrator POM).

I am using Intellij (community) to compile/debug these and I am unable to do so, Earlier these were made using Eclipse (.classpath , .project) and now the team (Management) wants to move to Intellij and VSTS CI.

**Some more Info**

1. Web application is packed as war and deployed to Tomcat using WIX on windows
2. Application some custom jars (no source available).
3. I have been asked to avoid using local repositories.
4. Multi module Project on Maven website / Github do not compile/ wants
   me to use `mvn clean install` for every dependent java project
5. ALL java projects are maven projects with POM.XML

**Questions :**

1. How to create a Multi Module Project using this structure (Which can
   also be imported in intellij/Eclipse).
2. How to compile the resulting multi module project with Maven/Intellij compile/debug .
3. Is Gradle more suitable here.

As a new Java Programmer , Its gets really difficult to change and deploy an already existing setup when you cannot connect/talk to the person who made it :( .
Any help/direction/suggestions will be really helpful.

Project Structure (JAVA)

```
C:\SomeProj\
├── Jars
|  ├── Java
|  |    └── extJar2.jar
|  |    └── extJar3.jar
|  |    └── extJar4.jar
|  |    └── extJar5.jar
|  |    └── javax.servlet-3.0.jar (Why is this externally required)
|  └── SomeFolder1
|  |    └── extJar1.jar
├── Source
|  ├── Common
|  |  ├── DAL (JAVA - jar) [Depends On Logger]
|  |  ├── Logger (JAVA - Jar)
|  ├── API
|  |  ├── DataInput
|  |  |  ├── InfoPuller (JAVA - Jar) [Depends On Logger]
|  |  ├── Info
|  |  |  └── MyWebApi (JAVA-WAR) [Depends On DAL and Logger]{Application to Build/Run/Deploy from Intellij/MAVEN}
|  |  └── Util
|  |     └── JobManager (JAVA - Jar) [Depends On Logger]
|  └── WebApp (Js App) {FrontEnd}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43932680/how-to-deploy-parent-project-packaging-war-in-maven/43933104#43933104

Answer (score 1):

1. I think your best bet is to create an aggregator project, in the most standard way possible (for example following the recommendations from here : https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html);
   If you're new to maven, it might look scary, but this can be as little as a single file (which can even be in a subfolder in one of your projects, although I don't recommend this, and suggest to have instead its own project). Having an aggregator will help a lot with modules that depend on other modules, etc.
   The resulting aggregated project can easily be imported in Eclipse/IntelliJ (Eclipse for example has a feature where it knows to import/create project files out of a pom.xml; IntelliJ has a similar feature).
2. The resulting project (if you set it up correctly) can be compiled/packaged via the default maven lifecycle, either with 
   `mvn compile` or `mvn package`. Obviously you can also run stuff via IDE, but you might need a little spadework (setting up runtimes/servers, etc).
   For example I build my projects for `CI` via maven, but I am also running them via eclipse, for development purposes. I'm using my pom.xmls as the Single Source of Truth.
3. You've just described what I believe to be a classic use-case for multi-module projects; You're asking for an opinionated answer which in the end boils down to "it depends what you prefer". I personally don't know Gradle, but I don't see elements in your description that look strange. So I think you can use Gradle if members of your team have better knowledge of Gradle vs Maven, etc.

Additional things to consider:

- On Application custom jars: If they do not exist in Maven Central repository, or in the provider's repository somewhere, and if you want to avoid local repositories, you can include a repository along with your project; this is basically just a flavor of local maven repository, with the distinct advantage that it can be packaged along with your projects, and other devs don't need to execute additional steps (i.e. they don't need to execute an extra step of adding artifacts to local repo). Some people don't like this approach, but if your constraints of "no local repo; no company repo" are unmovable, then I don't see any other way
- I don't understand very well what you say here:

> Multi module Project on Maven website / Github do not compile/ wants
>   me to use mvn clean install for every dependent java project.

I am going to assume that you mean that you've found some multi-module sample somewhere and it didn't worked for you. Without a concrete example, I can't really comment, except to mention that I have used multi-module builds in the past (and in the present), and they work fine for me.
Regarding your comment about `mvn clean install` - that's a maven command that install your project's/module's artifacts into local repository, and is not REALLY needed, unless these artifacts need to be consumed by projects external to your current multi-module build.